# Using PHP, Javascript, and HTML together

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery and Ajax with other scripts, getting data (sentences) from a MySQL database, calling PHP scripts with json_encode. However, I've found that json_encode doesn't handle certain characters (like a British pound sign, £). I need to clean up these sentences. So, I have a PHP script that gets the sentence ($sent) in its full form. I want to put it into an HTML div element. But, how do I pass the value of this variable to the jQuery ready function?

```
`        
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //$('div.inst').text("");
                $('h2').text("");
                $('h2').text("");
        });
        
`
```

In the PHP, in response to a MySQL query

```
`$sent = $row->sentence;`
```

I put the Javascript before the PHP. Does that matter?

Comment: Please either tell us (or post some code showing) exactly how you are getting these values, so that we know the method needed to inject the data into a div element.

Comment: json can handle anything you send at it. It's up to YOU to make sure the appropriate character sets are used. if you send in utf-8 to a (say) iso8859-1 context, you'll get mangled text at some point, and that includes any json you produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
utf8_decode(json_encode($data_to_be_returned))
```

Btw, if you're fetching your data from some `mysql` query, you can use something like `mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')`

Comment: I put mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8') into my original script that retrieves the sentences from my database. This worked in getting the English pound sign in the JSON call. But this doesn't answer the original question of how to pass data from PHP to the ready function.

Comment: as said, in the answer, you have to put this in your php code `utf8_decode(json_encode($data_to_be_returned))` Btw, don't forget to upvote if the answer satisfies you ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can just echo php out into your javascript. PHP executes on the server; JS on the client side.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   doSomething("<?= $sent ?>")
});
```

Comment: This didn't work. My Javascript code was as follows: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $('h2').text("<? $sent ?>");
});

Comment: Looks like you sorted it out?

Answer (score 0):

Tried with: `json_encode($whatever, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` ?

PHP 5.4 is needed for that...

Sounds weird that php is complaining about a dollar sign, what encoding is the string you are getting ?

About passing the json to the javascript i think you should do a php page who can get called by the ajax request and return that json_encode output as plain text with the appropriate headers, accepting the arguments you need ...

Comment: I'm not complaining about a dollar sign, but a pound sign. PHP wasn't complaining. The suggestion below managed to work.